# Sed cannot find file while building Docker image

Tags: sed, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build my very first Docker image. My image is based on `centos:7`. However, the Docker image gets stuck at this command:

```
RUN /usr/bin/sed -e 's/127.0.0.1:9000/9000/' \
        -e '/allowed_clients/d' \
        -e '/catch_workers_output/s/^;//' \
        -e '/error_log/d' \
        -i /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

This is what I get while the image is building:

```
Step 5 : RUN /usr/bin/sed -e 's/127.0.0.1:9000/9000/' ??????? -e '/allowed_clien
ts/d' ??????? -e '/catch_workers_output/s/^;//' ??????? -e '/error_log/d' ??????
? -i /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
 ---> Running in 660063647d37
/usr/bin/sed: can't read ???????: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read ???????: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read ???????: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/sed: can't read ???????: No such file or directory
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/sed -e 's/127.0.0.1:9000/9000/' ????
??? -e '/allowed_clients/d' ??????? -e '/catch_workers_output/s/^;//' ??????? -e
 '/error_log/d' ??????? -i /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

However, when I connect to the half-built image, the file is indeed there:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/docker$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED
VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              c34b6e6456bd        2 hours ago
295.7 MB
centos              7                   2b8d6139a545        2 days ago
212.1 MB
centos              centos7             2b8d6139a545        2 days ago
212.1 MB
centos              latest              2b8d6139a545        2 days ago
212.1 MB
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/docker$ docker run -it --rm c34b6e645
6bd
[root@b61b0154b97b /]# ls /etc/php-fpm.
php-fpm.conf  php-fpm.d/
[root@b61b0154b97b /]# ls /etc/php-fpm.d
www.conf
```

I've also verified that `sed` is located at `/usr/bin/sed`. In fact, I've pasted the command into my session and have seen it do its job.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: when testing, I would remove the `-i` in the sed command to prevent removing sensitive information. Once you are sure it works properly, add it again.

Comment: I would "wrap" all the commands onto one line, i.e. `sed  's/127.0.0.1:9000/9000/;/allowed_clients/d;/catch_workers_output/s/^;//;/error_log/d' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was misleading me. I realized that while copy and pasting, the `tab` character was not pasted properly.

I replaced those characters with `space` and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing if I run sed your command on my host; it looks like your the command is malformed with regard to the line-breaks.

I'd delete all the slashes and new lines and check it works. Then add them back in one at a time by hand, rather than cut and pasting.